# Why memset function doesn't work?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, memset

Why memset function doesn't work inside c++ function with char pointers?

```
void change(char* input){
  memset(input, 'a', strlen(input));
}

int main(){
  char* p = "foo";
  cout << p << endl;
  change(p);
  cout << p << endl;
}
```

Comment: This code should generate a compilation error in C++11 and later .. please use a modern compiler

Comment: Please note that a modifyable string literal is undefined behavior in C++

Comment: Even on older compilers, this should produce a warning with proper settings unless the compiler is *really* shitty.

Comment: no errors or warnings but prints original value

Comment: yes too, but i'm having a pointer not array

Comment: Cause it's undefined, anything can happen.

Comment: this is an example only, because i'm having a huge code. in there's an override function returns a char*. so i pass that char pointer to function change()....

Answer (score 3):

You attempt to modify a string literal. String literals are read-only, and you should use e.g. `const char*` when declaring pointers to them.

Modifying (or attempting to modify) constant or read-only data leads to *undefined behavior*.

If you want to modify the string, you need to use an array:

```
char p[] = "foo";
```

Comment: prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:11:13: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   char* p = "foo";

Is the corresponding gcc compiler msg

Comment: thanks but i want to do it using char pointers

Comment: because, [i have mentioned it in comments]

Comment: @EmmaAlex Inside your `change` function you have a pointer, isn't that enough? Otherwise you have to allocate memory, copy the string into that memory, call `change`, print the string and free the memory.

Comment: @EmmaAlex Or if some other function returns a pointer (to modifiable data) then just pass that pointer to `change`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude mm... thanks, can you send the code pls

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes i have done, but didn't works

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can i change the values of char pointer (original values: not const ) inside change function?

Comment: @EmmaAlex If you have a pointer to non-constant data, then you should be able to change that data. If it doesn't work then either the data must be constant, or there's something else going on that you're not telling us (like if the data is in a local array inside a function, and therefore has gone out of scope).